# Error while attaching a database: Unable to open the physical file "...project.mdf". Operating system error 5: "5(Access is denied.)

Tags: sql-server, database

Using windows authentication on SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) I detached database.

I am trying to attach database using another application, which has its own different user id for SQL attach process.
It is giving an error.

> Unable to open the physical file "...project.mdf". Operating system error 5: "5(Access is denied.)

Using SSMS and application's specific user id I tried to attach the database. It is giving the same error.

If both operations attaching and detaching are done using same user id there is no issue.

But requirement is to fix the issue while using different user IDs.
This does not get fixed even if both users have full control on MDF and ldf files / have admin privileges. Any idea how can this be done.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't use "Thanks", "Thanks in advance", "Sincerely", "Hi" or similar in questions. See here for why: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts

Comment: _If both operations attaching and detaching are done using same user id there is no issue._ That is not surprising. [Database Detach and Attach (SQL Server)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/database-detach-and-attach-sql-server) says, _File access permissions are set during a number of database operations, including detaching or attaching a database._